# Laravel 5.4 Collections - How to get data from collections by indexes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**You can read the last line, since everything on the first part is just an explanation for my situation. :)**

I saw a `syntax` before wherein I can get data from `collections` that is compacted into a `view` file with the use of `indexes/indices`.

So for my situation, I want to loop inside the blade with a `key` to serve as an index value using this syntax.

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value)
   {

   }
```

And now for my collections, I have 4 of it. `ref_codes`, `stocks`, `costs`, `prices`.

Here's the query on how I got them. (*It has a poor design, please suggest if there's a better query on getting everything uniquely.*)

```
        //Reference Code of Every Item
        $ref_codes = InventoryLogs::whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
            ->orderBy('ref_code', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('ref_code')
            ->get();

        //Stocks of Every Item
        $stock_ids = InventoryLogs::whereField('Stocks')
            ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
            ->select('ref_code', $latestupdate)
            ->orderBy('ref_code', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('ref_code')
            ->pluck('ID');

        $stocks = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$stock_ids)->get();

        //Cost of Every Item
        $cost_ids = InventoryLogs::whereField('Cost')
            ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
            ->select('ref_code', $latestupdate)
            ->orderBy('ref_code', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('ref_code')
            ->pluck('ID');

        $costs = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$cost_ids)->get();

        //Price of Every Item
        $price_ids = InventoryLogs::whereField('Price')
            ->whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
            ->select('ref_code', $latestupdate)
            ->orderBy('ref_code', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('ref_code')
            ->pluck('ID');

        $price = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$price_ids)->get();
```

And this will be my ideal loop for my blade:

```
                        <table id = "myTable" class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Reference Code</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Cost</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @forelse($ref_codes as $key => $ref_code)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$ref_code->ref_code}}</td>
                                    <td>$stocks[key]</td>
                                    <td>$costs[key]</td>
                                    <td>$prices[key]</td>
                                </tr>
                                @empty
                                @endforelse
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

And of course, `$stocks[key]` and the others don't work. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Just change your collections to array using `toArray()` so that you can use key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach `->toArray()` in each of following lines of your code,

```
$ref_codes = InventoryLogs::whereDate('created_at','>=', $request->datefrom)
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->dateto)
        ->orderBy('ref_code', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('ref_code')
        ->get()->toArray();

    $stocks = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$stock_ids)->get()->toArray();

    $costs = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$cost_ids)->get()->toArray();

    $prices = InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$price_ids)->get()->toArray();
```

Now, In your view iterate over each item of array like this to get desired data in your table like this:

```
<table id = "myTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Reference Code</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @forelse($ref_codes as $key => $ref_code)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$ref_code['ref_code']}}</td>
        <td>{{$stocks[$key]['column_name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$costs[$key]['column_name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$prices[$key]['column_name']}}</td>
    </tr>
    @empty
    @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer did the trick once again, haha. But it didn't solve my issue, but thanks to this, I knew that the structure of my queries are soooooo bad that it's prone to errors. :p

Comment: You need to optimize methods. Write a complex query to achieve what you want. General loops have slower execution than complex query execution

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the following changes in your code:

Add the **keyBy()** after the **get()**

```
InventoryLogs::whereIn('id',$cost_ids)->get()->keyBy('ref_code');
```

In the loop change the index to **$ref_code->ref_code**

```
$stocks[{$ref_code->ref_code}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forelse instead if you want to loop you better use foreach and you will get your indexes as follows

```
@foreach($ref_codes as $ref_code) 
<tr>
 <td>{{ $ref_code->ref_code}}</td>
 <td>{{ $ref_code->stocks }}</td> 
<td>{{ $ref_code->costs }}</td> 
<td>{{ $ref_code->prices }}</td> 
</tr>
 @endforeach
```